# Foundation Orbit Slider issue

Tags: slider, fancybox, zurb-foundation, lightbox, orbit

I have a little problem in my site using "Orbit slider" in a lightbox ("Fancybox"). It works very well at the beginning, but if you click on the next slide it suddenly disappears and it doesn't shows the sider, It only shows when you do a scale in the browser or if you clic on the inspector panel of the browser.

¿Any help?

Here's my github:

https://github.com/iontorres/Fortuna-Web-Site.git

And my code:

```
<article id="evento1" href="#proyecto1" class="branding_proyecto fancybox">     
        <img src="img/1910-color.jpg" alt="Hola, Aqui hay un proyecto de branding, en caso que no lo veas">
        <div class="branding_info_proyecto">
            <h1>BAR 1910</h1>
            <p>Branding / Web / Espacio </p>
        </div>
 </article>

<!-- ========  HERE GOES THE LIGHTBOX DE TAB BRANDING ============ -->
<div class="hide">
  <div id="proyecto1" class="info gallery">

    <a style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:400px; color:#fff; z-index:999; width:25px; height:25px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); padding: 0px 10px 10px 7px; font-size:18px; display:none;" id="btn" href="#" > + </a>

    <div class="proyect_inner_info">
      <a style="color:#fff; position:absolute; right:10px; font-size:24px;" id="btnx" href="#"> -     </a>

  <h1>NGS Nutrición y Genética Saludable</h1>
  <h2>Branding</h2>
  <p> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

    <ul class="example-orbit" data-orbit>
      <li class="active">
        <img src="img/ngs-slider1.jpg" alt="slide 1" />
      </li>
      <li >
        <img src="img/ngs-slider2.jpg" alt="slide 2" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/ngs-slider3.jpg" alt="slide 3" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/ngs-slider4.jpg" alt="slide 4" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/ngs-slider5.jpg" alt="slide 5" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/ngs-slider6.jpg" alt="slide 6" />
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From a quick look to your Git, you are including jQuery 3 times when you only need a single version, preferably the one that works with all your plugins (not necessarily the latest version)